# What are the typical components of job application packets for Lecturer/Assistant Professor positions at UK universities?

Tags: united-states, faculty-application, united-kingdom, assistant-professor, lecturer

I come from the US academic system (well, mostly), so please pardon my ignorance; I couldn't find a lot of information online so I ask this here. It appears to me that most of the UK lecturer/assistant professor job posts are not asking for anything more than just CV and Covering Letter. Is this the norm in UK? I am used to submitting several other documents for my US academic job applications, that includes research statement, teaching statement, and diversity statement. So I was wondering whether such statements are expected for UK lecturer/assistant professor job applications, even if they are not explicitly asked for.

In case if the search committees of UK universities, don't require separate research and teaching statements and rather want to see them as part of the covering letter, how   much details do they expect (in terms of past research, future goals, funding prospects, teaching philosophy, etc.)?. I presume that the covering letter shouldn't be longer than 2 pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a universal answer for UK universities. It will depend on the university and department.

When I was applying some combination of the following were asked for (not necessarily all):

- CV
- cover letter
- research statement/plans
- teaching statement/plans

A specific diversity statement was never asked for (I would address this through the other documents if possible).

If no specific statements are asked for address research/teaching briefly in the cover letter (2-3 pages max). Include as much detail as you can (especially specific figures rather than general statements), but focus on future plans rather than past work. The idea is to show that your plans are realistic and achievable at the department you're applying to (and you could get them funded). I would balance research/teaching based on the priorities of the department/university you're applying to.

I wouldn't submit documents that they didn't ask for. It's always worth asking to make sure you know what they are expecting.